# what is contextLoaderListerner in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have seen this code in web.xml file

```
<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

I build small sample app but i didn't used that before. whats the need of this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is used to load application configuration files when you first start your application.

http://www.javabeat.net/articles/18-introduction-to-spring-mvc-web-framework-web-tier-1.html